# How to get size of file in MB with js from "a" tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I woud like to ask how to get size of PDF on path that is in 'a' tag.

```
<p class="file-size" >            
    1.65
    <span id="velikost"></span> 
    MB
</p>
<a class="file-link" href="./pdf/bitcoin_cz.pdf" download="btc-white-paper.pdf">Download </a>
<span class="com-icon icon-download icon-color--info"></span>
```

I would like to have dynamic number instead of statick 1.65.

Comment: This depends on how you serve your HTML file. If you create it dynamically on your server (node, php whatever) you can fill up this information on the server before serving it. It is NOT possible to do it on the browser client only.

Comment: You could maybe look into using a XMLHttpRequest to get the meta information about the item

Comment: This is tricky to do with purely client-side technology, because you need to make a HEAD request to server for each individual file, and the server needs to supply the information in the response in a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Something like `fetch('./sample.pdf', {method: 'HEAD' }).then(res => res.headers.get('content-length'))` might be helpful?

Comment: The element is staticaly added

Comment: @MichaelHajný what do you mean by statically added? Do you use server side rendering?